# Update with Incrementing column

Tags: sql, db2

Example table:

```
Sample
------
id (primary key)
secondaryId (optional secondary key)
crtdate (created date)
... (other fields)
```

- Some users use `secondaryId` for identifying rows (i.e., *should* be unique)
- When the rows were created, `secondaryId` did not get a value, and was defaulted to `0`.
- Subsequently, rows were given a `secondaryId` value as they were used.
- I need to update all rows with value `0` to be the next available number.

Desired result (w/ simplified values):

```
   From:               To:

id secondaryId     id secondaryId
 1    0             1    7  // this is the max(secondaryId)+1
 2    0             2    8  // incrementing as we fill in the zeroes
 3    5             3    5  // already assigned
 4    0             4    9  // keep incrementing...
 5    6             5    6  // already assigned
```

This query would accomplish what I want to do; but alas, CTE + UPDATE is not supported:

```
with temp(primary, rownumber) as ( 
     values (
         select 
             id,
             row_number() over (partition by secondaryId order by crtdate)+6 --6 is max secondaryId
         from Sample
         where secondaryId='0'
     )
update Sample set secondaryId=temp.rownumber where Sample.id=temp.id
```

Does anyone have suggestions for a different way to approach this problem? I'm now suffering from tunnel vision...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **MERGE** statement as id is primary key and there won't be any duplicates.

```
MERGE INTO Sample as trgt
Using (
select id, 
       row_number() over (partition by secondaryId order by crtdate)+6  secondaryId
          --6 is max secondaryId
       from Sample where secondaryId='0'
     ) as src
ON( src.id= trgt.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trgt.secondaryid = src.secondaryId
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with `merge`; I'll have to research this.

Comment: Should `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trgt.id = src.id` instead be  `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET trgt.secondaryId = src.secondaryId`?

Comment: Yeah it should be SecondaryId, Updated the Columns in the Query

Answer (score 1):

For a Template method (not necessary to know max value), you can try this:

```
create table tmptable as (
    select f1.id, row_number() over(order by f1.crtdate) + ifnull((select max(f2.secondaryId) from Sample f2), 0) newsecondary
    from Sample f1 where f1.secondaryId='0'
) with data;

update Sample f1
set f1.secondaryId=(
                    select f2.newsecondary
                    from tmptable f2
                    where f2.id=f1.id
                   )
where exists 
(
    select * from tmptable f2
    where f2.id=f1.id

);

drop table tmptable;
```

Comment: Another interesting alternative; thanks.  I like the addition of `max()` to the query.  Performance question: does the subquery `select max(f2.secondaryId) from Sample f2`get executed on every iteration?

Comment: No only one time ;)

Comment: Verified this works.  Merge seems simpler to me, but good to know several ways to do something.  `ifnull` is a good reminder, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `UPDATE` a `SELECT` (well "fullselect"), which is probably the neatest solution here

```
create table sample (
    id int not null primary key
,   secondaryId int not null
,   crtdate date not null
)
;
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
 ( 1  ,  0   , current_date)
,( 2  ,  0   , current_date)
,( 3  ,  5   , current_date)
,( 4  ,  0   , current_date)
,( 5  ,  6   , current_date)
;
UPDATE (
    SELECT id, secondaryId
,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY secondaryId Desc) 
            + (SELECT MAX(id) from sample)      as new_secondaryId
    FROM
        sample s
    WHERE secondaryId = 0
    )
SET secondaryId = new_secondaryId
;
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html

Comment: Could it really be this simple?  Unfortunately, I'm running into `[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0104] Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: <IDENTIFIER>.`

Comment: The inner select works as expected, but when I try to update the select it complains...

Comment: What version of Db2 are you running? From the format of your error message I suspect it is DB2 for z/OS or DB2 for i.   My code works on reasonably recent DB2 for LUW versions,  but might well not be supported on the other two platforms. Ideally you should tag your question with the Db2 platform you are using.

Comment: It's on an IBMi.  I wasn't aware of the differences between the platforms. 
 It's a real shame; I like the simplicity of your answer.